# Multiple slick `column`s for the same DB column break projection

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I'm new to Slick thus I'm not sure whether the problem caused by incorrect usage of implicits or Slick doesn't allow doing what I'm trying to do.

In short I use [Slick-pg](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg) extension for JSONB support in Postgres. I also use `spray-json` to deserialize JSONB fields into case classes.

In order to automagically convert columns into objects I wrote generic implicit `JsonColumnType` that you can see below. It allows me to have any case class for which I defined json formatter to be converted to jsonb field.

On the other hand I want to have alias of `JsValue` type for the same column so that I can use [JSONB-operators](https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/com/github/tminglei/slickpg/json/PgJsonExtensions.scala).

```
import com.github.tminglei.slickpg._
import com.github.tminglei.slickpg.json.PgJsonExtensions
import org.bson.types.ObjectId
import slick.ast.BaseTypedType
import slick.jdbc.JdbcType
import spray.json.{JsValue, RootJsonWriter, RootJsonReader}
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

trait MyPostgresDriver extends ExPostgresDriver with PgArraySupport with PgDate2Support with PgRangeSupport with PgHStoreSupport with PgSprayJsonSupport with PgJsonExtensions with PgSearchSupport with PgNetSupport with PgLTreeSupport {

  override def pgjson = "jsonb" // jsonb support is in postgres 9.4.0 onward; for 9.3.x use "json"
  override val api = MyAPI
  private val plainAPI = new API with SprayJsonPlainImplicits

  object MyAPI extends API with DateTimeImplicits with JsonImplicits with NetImplicits with LTreeImplicits with RangeImplicits with HStoreImplicits with SearchImplicits with SearchAssistants { //with ArrayImplicits

    implicit val ObjectIdColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[ObjectId, Array[Byte]](
      { obj => obj.toByteArray }, { arr => new ObjectId(arr) }
    )

    implicit def JsonColumnType[T: ClassTag](implicit reader: RootJsonReader[T], writer: RootJsonWriter[T]) = {
      val columnType: JdbcType[T] with BaseTypedType[T] = MappedColumnType.base[T, JsValue]({ obj => writer.write(obj) }, { json => reader.read(json) })
      columnType
    }
  }
}

object MyPostgresDriver extends MyPostgresDriver
```

Here is how my table is defined (minimized version)

```
case class Article(id : ObjectId, ids : Ids)
case class Ids(doi: Option[String], pmid: Option[Long])

class ArticleRow(tag: Tag) extends Table[Article](tag, "articles") {

  def id = column[ObjectId]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def idsJson = column[JsValue]("ext_ids")
  def ids = column[Ids]("ext_ids")

  private val fromTuple: ((ObjectId, Ids)) => Article = {
    case (id, ids) => Article(id, ids)
  }
  private val toTuple = (v: Article) => Option((v.id, v.ids))

  def * = ProvenShape.proveShapeOf((id, ids) <> (fromTuple, toTuple))(MappedProjection.mappedProjectionShape)
}

private val articles = TableQuery[ArticleRow]
```

Finally I have function that looks up articles by value of json field

```
def getArticleByDoi(doi : String): Future[Article] = {
  val query = (for (a <- articles if (a.idsJson +>> "doi").asColumnOf[String] === doi) yield a).take(1).result
  slickDb.run(query).map { items =>
    items.headOption.getOrElse(throw new RuntimeException(s"Article with doi $doi is not found"))
  }
}
```

Sadly I get following exception in runtime

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: spray.json.JsObject cannot be cast to server.models.db.Ids
```

The problem is in [SpecializedJdbcResultConverter.base](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick/src/main/scala/slick/jdbc/SpecializedJdbcResultConverters.fm#L16-L27) where `ti.getValue` is being called with wrong `ti`. It should be `slick.driver.JdbcTypesComponent$MappedJdbcType` but instead it's `com.github.tminglei.slickpg.utils.PgCommonJdbcTypes$GenericJdbcType`. As result wrong type is passed into my tuple converter.

What makes Slick choose different type for column even though there is explicit definition of projection in table row class ?

Sample project that demonstrates the issue is [here](https://github.com/cppexpert/slick-columns-test).

Comment: @cvogt Could you please take a look at this too ? Thanks!